# different execution time for same query where different values in where clause

Tags: sql, sap-ase, sql-execution-plan

Dears,
I run the same query and it takes different execution times as the following:
the query is :

```
select * from table1 where userID = 2
```

it scans the non cluster index idx1  which contains the userID as one of its keys, so I get the results in 5 seconds.
BUT when I run it again with userID = 5 
it scans the non cluster index idx2 which not contains userID as one of its keys, and get the results after 2 HOURS, I think it maybe read the whole table to find the userID = 5

what is the cause of this problem??
maybe the value of userID = 5 is not in the idx1 leaf??
I think the leaf level in NC index stores a range of values and the query run well for userID =4 and for userID = 6 so userID = 5 should be in the leaf level,

please advice

Comment: Try updating the `statistics` of the table

Comment: please post actual execution plan and schema of table

Comment: if userID is a foreign key, you should have a dedicated index for it and these problems should not occur

Comment: Thank you Dears, I will update statistics and return to record the results. But I still not Know the actual cause related to idx1 index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First update statistics of the indexes of that tables.
If it does not work and you're using ASE15 or +, you should update statistics of the column userID. The ASE15 optimizer is more sensitive to statistics than ASE12.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dears, I tried to update index statistics for this table and all tables related to it in the real environment and the problem was solved. and I tried in test environment to update index statistics just for this table but no improvement , then I update column statistics of userID and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use index hint

**For the hot fix**

`select * from table1 with(index(idx1) where userID = 5`

Ref: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/08/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint-part2/

**For the long term solution**

You might need to update statistic of the table or rebuild the index.
You can follow this linke: [Script for rebuilding and reindexing the fragmented index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086812/script-for-rebuilding-and-reindexing-the-fragmented-index)

Comment: it is not a good idea to force the usage of an index, if the optimizer is not using it.. there is a reason..

Comment: Thank you Dears, I don't prefer to use index hint because the mentioned query is part of Report Generation application in my company and we cannot edit the code.