# How to rebuild a sql index

Tags: php, sql

My sql data base includes index numbers with lots of gaps between

```
id = 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 25, ...
```

because some data sets together with the corresponding index have been deleted. I would like to rebuild this automatic incrementing index in a way, that index numbers with no gaps are shown in the data base.

```
id = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
```

What would the correct sql statement look like?

I have tried something like

```
ALTER TABLE table1 . id REBUILD
```

but this includes syntax errors.

Comment: you can try to drop primary key and then add it back like this `alter table table-name add column `id` int(10) unsigned primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thru designer. Go to `Table`-->`Index` then right click on index and select `Rebuild`.

**Similar question,** 
[Script for rebuilding and reindexing the fragmented index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086812/script-for-rebuilding-and-reindexing-the-fragmented-index)

Answer (score 0):

NO, NO, NO

Don't ever do this. If you think you'll have to do it, you have a wrong approach.

ID stands for "identifier" and it sole purpose is to UNIQUELY identify the associated data.

Create a second column "sequence" for this, which is under YOUR control and let the database have THEIR way to handle data.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, however there are no simple sql expressions with a clear syntax to rebuild an index. Therefore I deleted the index column in my data base and added a new index column with the same name. This worked perfect.  The data lines were automatic numbered in a series from 1,2, 3, ..., N. Of course, first I saved the data base with a new name by the copy command.

Comment: You're still abuisng the id field for another purpose... why are you using autoincrement then anyway?